# Eclipse plugin dev - How to show default IResource context menu in non-text custom editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, popup, swt

I´m writing an Eclipse plugin to show the contents of an own file type in an own custom editor.
This file basically consists of 1..n IFile´s from the Project Explorer which are shown in a SWT TreeView. 
The entries in this TreeView are some Beans organized in a flat List, but i provide an adapter to convert them to IFile´s.

```
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters">
      <factory
            adaptableType="de.dstg.delta.collections.model.Collection$Member"
            class="de.dstg.delta.collections.CollectionMemberAdapterFactory">
         <adapter
               type="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource2">
         </adapter>
         <adapter
               type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
         </adapter>
      </factory>
  </extension>
```

[Eclipse Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSqI.jpg)

It´s no problem to show a custom SWT menu but i think the right way is using the Eclipse menu structure, especially by providing default behaviour for Resources.
How can i show the default context popup menu, which is used by right-clicking resources in the Project Explorer, in my SWT TableView?

**EDIT** second question removed

**EDIT2**
According to the answer from greg-449, the problem remains that the context menu shows no entries i would like to have for this type of selection. 
f.e. i need **delete** or **open with** or something like that 'file basics' without implementing it on my own.

We have also some other menus from additional plugins that should be visible here when the appropriate file type is selected. This works in Project Explorer but not in my table view.

I think the problem is the type of the selected element.
Plugin spy shows the following in my table view:
type of the selected element: `Collection$Member`,
interfaces valid for the selected element: `IAdaptable`
whereas the Project Explorer shows `File` and `IFile`, respectively.

My adapter works generally and delivers the related `IFile` while being triggered from an unknown Eclipse source.
I think i have to explicitely say, that the context menu should use the `IFile` type to get the correct menu entries but i dont´t know how.
Or did i miss something?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a 'default' menu. Some menu items are defined to be added to all popup menus that define a specific place holder.

To use the place holder you must register your context menu with Eclipse, something like:

```
private void createContextMenu(Viewer viewer) {
    Control menuControl = viewer.getControl();
    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopUp"); 
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager mgr) {
            fillContextMenu(mgr);
        }
    });
    Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(menuControl);
    menuControl.setMenu(menu);

    // register the context menu such that other plugins may contribute to it
    getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
}

private void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menu) {
    // TODO add your actions

    // Standard additions
    menu.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
}
```

You will probably also need to set your viewer as the 'selection provider':

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

Many menu items will check this to see what the type of the current selection is.

There is nothing that will automatically give you things like Open With or Delete, you have to add these yourself in the 'fillContextMenu' section.

You can use `org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu` for Open With.

```
IFile file = ... currently selected file

IMenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Open With...");
submenu.add(new OpenWithMenu(getSite().getPage(), file);
menu.append(submenu);
```

Comment: The selection provider was already set but registering the menu did the trick. Thanks! I´ve updated my question above to solve the remaining part. Please have a look :)